# U-SQL skipping 0 Length Files

Tags: u-sql

I am trying to skip 0 length files (files that exist but are 0 bytes) on input, I suspect there is already a feature to do this and I can't find the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Files of zero bytes are considered as files with zero lines. You don't need to skip them explicitly.

Comment: I have updated my Build of U-SQL I tried to use the FileSet method but received errors on the file names... I went ahead and used the * syntax on the root of the directory, The directory has 3329 files, 99% of the files are 0 Length. The job has been running 18 minutes and read exactly 1.5MB and output 346K. I am really not understanding why this would take longer than processing 150 100 MB files? It would be great if the code would work, IF(FILE.LENGTH(@input)>0) THEN **DO STUFF** would... Any help out there? Thanks!